# Subgroup presentation for image of group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

In general, given a finitely presented group, it's not possible to find a presentation for an arbitrary subgroup without some other condition like finite index. I was wondering though if one was given two finitely presented groups $G$ and $H$, and a homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$, is there a method for finding a presentation of the subgroup $f(G)\subset H$ in terms of generators and relations of $G$ and $H$?

Comment: Note that $f(G)$ is not necessarily finitely presented.

Comment: By considering the case when $G$ is free group, you can see that  finding a presentation of an arbitrary subgroup of a finitely presented group is a special case of your problem, and you have already remarked that that cannot be done in general.